# Why we need list constructor to create an list in python. what are the advantages and disadvantages

Tags: python, list

Recently i started learning python and i got struck in list i couldn't understand the use of list() constructor in python when we can create an list just by using square bracket. 
eg : mylist=['BMW', 'AUDI', 'SAAB']

Could anyone explain

Answer (score 0):

The `list` builtin is useful for converting other iterables into lists, for example, `list(range(10))`.